# How to query by number and desconsider special characters

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

currently I have a document in my opensearch database with the value `1301-003.023`.
If I run the following query the document will be returned:

```json
GET test/example
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_number": "1301-003.023"
    }
  }
}
```

the main problem is if the user run this query:

```json
GET test/example
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_number": "1301003.023"
    }
  }
}
```

In the query above the symbol `-` is missing, and it will returning nothing. I need to create a search that can deal with it but without return documents that doesn't have the exactly same numbers. So, if i search for `1301003023` I want to find the document with `1301-003.023`, but I don't for documents with `1301-003.032` (see that the last two numbers were exchanged)

Answer (score 0):

I created a new analyzer using char filter that mapping simbols "." and "-" to empty. So, the number "1301-003.023" becomes token "1301003023".

Full example:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            ". => ",
            "- => "
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_number": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Document

```
POST test/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"my_number": "1301-003.023"}
```

Query

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_number": {
        "query": "1301003023"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results

```
    "hits": [
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_id": "MC7v0IUBKJKciEqCrBP-",
    "_score": 0.2876821,
    "_source": {
      "my_number": "1301-003.023"
    }
  }
```